# WatiN - Selecting a drop down menu from pop up

Tags: popup, watin, automated-tests

I am currently trying to set up WatiN to do some automated testing of a new CRM solution.  We have a screen button called Advanced Find. 
When this button is clicked, a new pop up opens.  This popup has a drop down menu and I would like to click it and select on option from it.

The code for the pop up window is:

```
td class="ms-crm-AdvFind-Label"><br>
td class="ms-crm-AdvFind-EntityList"> <br>
select name="slctPrimaryEntity" class="ms-crm-SelectBox " id="slctPrimaryEntity"     Sort="ascending" defaultSelected="activitypointer"><br>
option title="Organisations" value="account">
```

The WatiN code I have is as follows:

```
ie.Image(Find.ByClass("ms-crm-ImageStrip-advancedfind32")).Click();
IE poppedUpBrowser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Advanced Find - Microsoft Dynamics CRM"));
SelectList ddl = poppedUpBrowser.SelectList(Find.ByClass("ms-crm-AdvFind-Label")&(Find.ById("slctPrimaryEntity")));<br>
ddl.Option("Organisations").Select();<br>
Assert.That(ddl.SelectedItem.Equals("Organisations"));<br>
```

Can someone please point out where I have gone wrong.

Thanks.

Edit:

I am currently getting this error message when running the test:

```
Failure: WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException : Could not find OPTION element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'innertext' equals 'Organisations' ignoring case at http://website

Stack Trace:
at WatiN.Core.Element.get_NativeElement()
at WatiN.Core.Element.GetAttributeValueImpl(String attributeName)
at WatiN.Core.Component.GetAttributeValue(String attributeName)
at WatiN.Core.Option.setSelected(Boolean value, Boolean WaitForComplete)
at WatiN.Core.Option.Select()
```

Edit: More HTML code:

```
<tbody>
<tr height="100%">
<td class="AdvFind_td_FindBody">
<span id="advancedFind">
<table class="ms-crm-AdvFindControl" id="advFind" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" EntityName="activitypointer" UIProvider="" DataProvider="" EntityTypeCode="4200" DisableValueControlInSimpleMode="0" DistinctFetch="1" SaveChangesAlert="1" IncludeUserQuery="1" IncludeSystemQuery="1" ValidQueryType="0" FilterControlVisible="1" TitleVisible="0" EntityListVisible="1" RelatedEntitiesVisible="1" QueryListVisible="1" CanCreateUserQuery="1" CanWriteUserQuery="1" IncludeAPIQuery="0" FetchMode="2" Buttons="1023" Modes="3" Mode="1" aliasesInInitialFetch="">
<tbody>
<tr class="ms-crm-AdvFind-TitleArea">
<td>
<table class="ms-crm-AdvFind-Title-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ms-crm-AdvFind-EntityList">
<select name="slctPrimaryEntity" class="ms-crm-SelectBox " id="slctPrimaryEntity" Sort="ascending" defaultSelected="activitypointer">
<option title="Activities" value="activitypointer">
<option title="Addresses" value="customeraddress">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the popup inside a frame. If so, you will need to traverse from the Frame.
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, the popup had a frame on it, I found that and then used the info from below to select the item.

Answer (score 0):

Change the assert to

```
Assert.That(ddl.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Organisations"));
```

SelectedItem is of type Option where "Organisations" is of type String so you can't compare the two values. By using the Text property you will get the needed results.

**EDIT:** As far as your edit goes - yes, you don't have an element with **text** "Organisations". You have to find what you want to select by using the existing attributes you have - the title or the value. So the solution for the error is to use the Find class:

```
ddl.Option(Find.ByTitle("Organisations")).Select();
```

or

```
ddl.Option(Find.ByValue("account")).Select();
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the help.<br>  I am still getting the same error as above with the new line as you suggested. <br>  Is there something else that I can try.  I can add more code from the site if required.  Thanks.

Comment: Well the selectlist's html would be helpful

Comment: Could there be an issue if the SelectList is created by javascript?  When I look at the page using F12 Developer Tools, I get the generated HTML, but if I look at the page DOM, its all in script.

Comment: Well try to add a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) in order to leave time for the javascript to load. If that's the case you should add some wait events.

Comment: Cheers for that, however thats not worked either.  I will edit the main post to show more of the code